java: module not found: tess4j requires tess4j;
First of all: I'm completely new to Tess4j and trying to get image recognition in Java.
So I setup a gradle project with JavaFX and Tess4j in vscode. The IDE has no problem finding the dependencies in the code itself and even suggest to autocomplete requires tess4j; in my module-info.java. Before adding Tess4j the application was working fine. The build failes with:
java: module not found: tess4j requires tess4j;

and if I still try to run it, it says:
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module supermarket not found

So this is my build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '3.0.1'
    
}

javafx {
    version = "22.0.1"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.swing' ]
}

jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'supermarket'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation libs.junit.jupiter
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    implementation libs.guava
    implementation group: 'net.sourceforge.tess4j', name: 'tess4j', version: '5.13.0'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(19)
    }
}

application {
    mainClass = 'supermarket'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

and this is my module-info.java:
module supermarket {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;

    requires java.desktop;
    requires javafx.swing; 

    requires tess4j;

    opens supermarket to javafx.fxml;
    exports supermarket;
}

I tried to search if anyone else got the same problem or a similar one, but wasn't successful. I always got to the point that you should just be able to add the dependencies and it should work. But it just won't

Gradle build - add module path

Hello, did you download the Tesseract file? You'll need to download the local library and add its path to the system's environment variables.
